# Why is there a large "well-shaped" distortion when the input voltage exceeds the power rails of an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, saturation

The specific model in question is the LM258 op-amp. After looking at its datasheet I understand why the output swing at both the positive and negative voltages, however I don't understand the physical scientific reason as to why the waveform distorts when the input pk-pk voltage is increased significantly beyond the power rails (+-6V) . In the shown diagram, the input peak-to-peak voltage is only 14 V and there is significant well formation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this what they call phase reversal?

Comment: Define 'well-shaped'. Clipping of sine waves isn't generally considered as such.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have exceeded the common mode range of the inputs. When you do so, the output voltage is undefined.

There is also "inversion" or "phase reversal", and cannot easily be explained by simply looking at the schematic. It is, however, a well-known behavior- see, for example, [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa277/sloa277.pdf?ts=1621437074961&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) document.

> **Input Common Mode Range**
>
> The recommended common mode range is 0 V (relative to the negative supply) to VCC – 2 V over the full
> temperature range. However, the actual upper common mode range varies by approximately 4 mV/°C,
> with cold temperatures reducing the upper limit of the common mode voltage range.
> Note that when used as a comparator, only one input needs to be within the common mode range. The
> other input can be above the common mode range or above VCC and the output will be the expected VOH
> level (for Vin+ > Vin–) or VOL level (for Vin – > Vin+). If both inputs exceed the upper common mode range,
> the output is undefined; it could be either the VOL or VOH level and the result may vary part-to-part, lot-tolot, over process, over temperature, etc. **If either input or both inputs are lower than –0.3 V with respect to
> the negative supply, excessive input current can flow and the output may display phase reversal, also
> called inversion.**
> Because the inputs have no internal diodes to VCC, the input voltage can exceed the VCC voltage. If this
> occurs, the input will block current flow due to a reverse biased diode forming in the input PNP transistor.
> Current flow is blocked even if VCC equals 0 V. If either input or both inputs exceed maximum the VCC
> rating, junction breakdown can occur. This may lead to permanent device damage per the table notes in
> the respective device's data sheet Absolute Maximum Ratings table.

Not all models adequately replicate that behavior, nor do they necessarily go wonky where the input common range is exceeded. At 25°C the input common mode range is at least to 4.5V with a 6V supply, and your model seems to misbehave at 4V in.

Also, in reality, applying a negative voltage relative to the "GND" pin directly to an input from a low impedance source can easily destroy the chip.

Comment: Thank you, @spehropefhany I have had a look at the document that you have linked and on page 8 titled "Phase reversal", it says it occurs when the common mode voltage range is violated. From the data sheet the max value for the common mode voltage range is (V+)-1.5V for the LM358 amplifier. I have used V+ as 6, so therefore, the max value after which phase reversal should become apparent should be 4.5 V if I am not mistaken. However, from the graph linked in my original question, the formation of the well occurs at about 6.6 V for the input voltage. What am I misunderstanding? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's simply exceeding the input common mode range, which is V+ - 2.0V for the LM358 over temperature.

Comment: I see, but what I am wondering is, why does the well form at an input of 6.6 V and not at an input of 4.5 V?

Comment: The datasheet says it's undefined so it can do whatever it likes after 4V or 4.5V. The transistors are completely starved above about 5.9V so you might expect something to happen there in reality. It might be worth testing and seeing what it really does. It may not match the model.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This has been very helpful :)

Comment: For what it's worth, one sample of a real part does not exhibit that behavior. The output simply rails and stays there.

Answer (score 5):

> There is also "inversion" or "phase reversal", and cannot easily be explained by simply looking at the schematic.

Yes, it can.  The LM358 simplified internal schematic in the datasheet leaves out a lot of stuff, but it does show the main signal path.  In the input overdrive condition:

Q2 and Q3 are reverse-biased and shut off.  There now is no current through Q8 to mirror into Q9, so they both stop conducting, and Q8 and Q9 shut off.  There now is no base current path for Q10, so it shuts off.  The 4.0 uA current source pulls the Q11 base high, turning on Q12, turning on Q13, pulling the output low.

Answer (score 4):

You can not drive the input greater than the Vdd on that Op Amp but some are Rail to rail input and output. But LMV321 input is only to V- rail on input,

Your OA **cannot** do rail to rail on the input or the output, and **especially you cannot exceed the Vcm input range**.

You violated the Vin- max specs and the Vcm range specs.. note : the absolute max input is controlled by a Schottky diode voltage.
[image]

**Very close to thermal damage of front end.**

- otherwise the output stage saturates to the negative maximum, which in this case appears as a phase reversal but is just a shutdown of the front end bias.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. The OP is asking the explanation for the output wave shape when the OA is overdriven, not the conditions to overdrive it

Comment: Thanks Barry, nice to see someone as old as dirt here like me. ;)

Comment: Probably even older (I got my EE degree in 1967). Thanks for updating your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found this simplified internal schematic on one version of the LM358 datasheet:

[image: LM358]

If you look at the configuration of the differential pair at the input, you may see what is happening, and why the distortion is just "flat" at the negative end of the cycle and "well-shaped" at the positive end.

The transistors Q1 - Q4 are turning off when you drive it positive within the two BE junction drops of the V+ rail.  (There's more to it than that, but it's the basic idea.)

Since you are in a voltage-follower configuration, both sides are driven up.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, this behavior is referred to as phase reversal in datasheets. Newer op-amps (not more than a few decades old) have circuitry to prevent it and will show this bonus in their datasheets. Example:

[image]

So if you cannot avoid leaving the input common mode range in your application and require the output to saturate instead of reverse, then consider some more modern opamps. E.g. for an audio input amplifier, the saturation produces a less audible distortion as compared to the positive peaks being flipped over.